# Textview and button inside the relativelayout not get visible in android oreo and pie but visible in other android version perfectly

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-9.0-pie

Textview and button inside the relativelayout not get visible in android oreo and pie but visible in other android version perfectly.

```
if (mPromocodeCheckBox != null) {
            mPromocodeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (inputMethodManager == null)
                        inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) ALTCommonUtils.currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                    if (mPromocodeLayout != null) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            mPromocodeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if (inputMethodManager != null && mPromocodeEditText != null) {
                                mPromocodeEditText.requestFocus();
                                inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mPromocodeEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                            }
                            if (mPromocodeApplyButton != null)
                                mPromocodeApplyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            if (mPromocodeEditText != null)
                                mPromocodeEditText.setEnabled(true);
                        } else {
                            mPromocodeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            HandleViewsUtils.TextView_SetText(mPromocodeMsg, "");

                            if (inputMethodManager != null && mPromocodeEditText != null) {
                                HandleViewsUtils.EditText_SetText(mPromocodeEditText, "");
                                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mPromocodeEditText.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

For you reference i has attached the screenshot of xml code :
[image]

[image]

[image]

1st screenshot shows the normal screen for both below oreo and above oreo
[image]

2nd screenshot shows perfectly when i click promocode checkbox in below oreo :
[image]

3rd screenshot shows imperfect when i click promocode checkbox in oreo and pie
[image]

Comment: can you share xml code ?

Comment: when i am trying to add xml code , its showing following error "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more detail"

Comment: you can try replacing previous shared code with xml code

Comment: share your xml file as well.

Comment: Sorry guys , i cant attach the xml code, instead i had attached screenshot .

Comment: Adding the UI (on device/emulator) screen-shots would've been better and can you reattach a cleaner screenshot of your layout, those colours make it distracting.

Comment: I have attached the UI screen shot with the question @MDNaseemAshraf

Comment: try using native TextView which AndroidStudio provides

Comment: My checkbox is not a native checkbox but its working fine in oreo and pie.Then why should i change custom textview to native textview

Comment: I've found the issue check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml screenshots were painful to read but, I just realized you're using **fill_parent instead of match_parent**. **FILL_PARENT** is deprecated in API 8 afterwards; [Google Developer Documentation Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams#constants_2). [Why you should use Match Parent](https://www.randomlytyping.com/blog/2014/2/9/matchparent-vs-fillparent).

Maybe it's time you moved towards the more recently introduced methods, design patterns and libraries. Start using Constraint Layout instead of Relative Layout. [Benefits of Constraint Layout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html) and its [introduction in Android Studio 2.2](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html) onwards. *Stop using Relative Layouts* and use them only when *very* necessary. Google I/O Talk of 2018 on Layouts, [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrMw7MEgADk&feature=youtu.be&t=1207). You don't know when Google will decide to deprecate it and then you'd have projects that will stop working.

Another thing to keep in mind is the new Support Library [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx), to which you should start migrating your older projects. AndroidX will be the new *singular* support library for future and all that weird number based support libraries will be discontinued.

The last most important thing is **you should start developing for Android API 28+** which will be enforced by Google from this year onwards; Google Developers [Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/Mon18umAVK4). So, start migrating to current APIs and support library.

Hope this helps.

**Addendum**
Make sure of Android Studio's alerts on your codebase regarding deprecation. More links here;

- [@Deprecated annotation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Deprecated)
- [Improve your code with lint checks.](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint)
- [Behavior changes: apps targeting API level 28+.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28)

Comment: i had changed match_parent instead of fill_parent. Eventhough i didnt get solution for this issue

Comment: Keep it changed to match_parent. Forget fill_parent. Replace your Relative Layout with a Constraint Layout and build and run the project. See if that gives you your required ui on oreo and above versions. Also, attach XML layout to question.

Comment: Also, as far as I can recall, if id has been defined, by @+id, you only need to call it by @id later onwards in the file. Try that too. Only the first occurrence of the id from top-down would have "@+id".

Comment: IN my case i have added extra linear layout for custom checkbox , then its working fine in oreo and pie version